# Bitmap image not showing up in canvas

Tags: javascript, createjs, easeljs

I need some direction here as I'm not clear on what I'm doing wrong. All I'm trying to do is a load a bitmap in the center of the canvas but it's not showing up. My file path is correct and I don't see what I might have coded incorrectly, where am I going wrong?

```
var canvas, stage, centerX, centerY;

function init() {
    'use strict';

    canvas = document.getElementById("easel");
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    centerX = canvas.width / 2;
    centerY = canvas.height / 2;

    var ship = new createjs.Bitmap("../images/millenium.png"),
        shipCenterX = ship.width / 2,
        shipCenterY = ship.height / 2;

    ship.x = centerX;
    ship.y = centerY;
    ship.regX = shipCenterX;
    ship.regY = shipCenterY;

    stage.addChild(ship);
    stage.update();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The way this library appears to handle drawing to the canvas is by calling `stage.update()` which they recommend attaching to their "tick" event (e.g. http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Stage.html)

Basically, we need to keep continually redrawing the canvas, and createjs gives us a method to do that, like so:

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", handleTick);
function handleTick(event) {
     stage.update();
}
```

However, since you haven't made your `stage` globally accessible, I tweaked your init function slightly so that we can access `stage` by returning it at the end of the function. Thus you can set `stage` in the global scope to the result of the function:

```
var stage = init();
```

And `handleTick` will use that `stage` by default. However if you're thinking of reusing your objects outside of your `init()` function, you may want to consider passing them to the init function or keeping their initial data structure outside of the `init` function to make them easier to access.

https://jsfiddle.net/jpgw1oka/

Comment: The key here is that you have to ensure the stage updates *after* the image has been loaded.

Answer (score 0):

And make sure you are loading the CreateJS library: https://code.createjs.com/createjs-2015.11.26.min.js.

Remove the 'use strict'.

And make sure you are declaring your variables and function calls inside a `window.onload` event listener.

E.g.

```
var canvas, stage;

function init() {

canvas = document.getElementById("easel");
stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

var ship = new createjs.Bitmap("../images/millenium.png");

ship.x = Math.floor(stage.canvas.width * 0.5);
ship.y = Math.florr(stage.canvas.height * 0.5);
ship.regX = Math.floor(ship.image.width * 0.5);
ship.regY = Math.floor(ship.image.height * 0.5);

stage.addChild(ship);
stage.update();

}
```